# What is the best way to merge 36 sql tables into one table. They all have the same structure. The tables contain monthly POS data

Tags: sql

What is the best way to merge 36 SQL tables into one table.  They all have the same structure.  The tables contain monthly POS data.

Comment: Use `union all`.

Comment: Why do you want to merge them and what do you mean by merge? BTW, the answer is obvious, insert all rows from 35 tables into the 36th table. Please provide more explanation to make your question clear.

Comment: Please EDIT your question to add more detail

Comment: I have 36 tables that contain monthly point of sales information.  I need to do a promotional reconciliation.  I have deal sheets that contain various promotion that occur throughout the year.  A deal sheet can contain multiple items and the promotion period can expend to different months.  For example there is $0.50 discount for item "A"  from July 15, 2015 thru August 15, 2015 and I have to determine how many items were sold during the period.  In this scenario I have to join two tables.  Another promotion could be for 3 or 4 months which means I need to join 3 or 4 tables and so on.

Comment: Having one big table to join against my promotional field would be easier

Comment: Have a think now about how often you will be doing this. You might want to consider a longer term solution (i.e. when the next table is created). A long term solution might be a reporting data warehouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be multiple ways of doing this, here is one:

```
CREATE TABLE finaltable (col1, col2, col3...) -- Creates a new table to put all other 36 tables into.

INSERT INTO finaltable (col1, col2, col3...) -- This will insert data from other tables into the finaltable. 
SELECT (col1, col2, col3...) 
FROM table1  -- you can repeat this step 36 times for all the tables. just change from "table1" to your table name.
```

Comment: Make sure you name the columns correctly tho, Name all the columns in the finaltable, same as the columns you are trying to extract from the other 36 tables.

Comment: I'm going to use the following statement to create an empty table with the same schema Select Top 0 * into <NewTable> from <OldTable> the I'll use this statement "Insert into <NewTable> Select * from Table[1..36]"